# Maximal possible dimension of an abelian Lie subalgebra of Heisenberg Lie algebra of dimension $2n+1$.

Tags: lie-algebras

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $\mathfrak{h}_n$ denote the Heisenberg Lie algebra of dimension $2n+1$ (over any given field $k$). Namely, $\mathfrak{h}_n$ is the Lie algebra with basis $x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n, c$ and with the Lie bracket defined by$$[x_i, y_j] = \delta_{ij}c,\text{ }[x_i, x_j] = [y_i, y_j] = [x_i, c] = [y_j, c] = 0$$(where $1 \le i, j \le n$ and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta). My question is, what is the maximal possible dimension of an abelian Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{h}_n$?

Comment: Cross-posted on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222084/maximal-possible-dimension-of-abelian-lie-subalgebra-of-heisenberg-lie-algebra-o

Answer (score 3):

The maximal dimension of an abelian subalgebra of $\mathfrak{h}_n$ is equal to $n+1$. One direction is easy. Obviously $\langle x_1,\ldots ,x_n,c\rangle $ is an abelian subalgebra of dimension $n+1$. The non-trivial part is to show that there is no abelian subalgebra of dimension $n+2$. This can be found in the thesis of M. Ceballos [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjABahUKEwjd2cy1ztPHAhXqlXIKHYUKDvo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.educacion.gob.es%2Fteseo%2FimprimirFicheroTesis.do%3Ffichero%3D34474&ei=hW_kVZ2DMOqrygOFlbjQDw&usg=AFQjCNHlHCpvmbDpFH_hNF2sZpcLhra0nw), in particular reference [78]. There is also an argument in the paper on a refinement of Ado's theorem [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_07_ado.pdf), for Heisenberg Lie algebras. Note that the maximal dimension of an abelian subalgebra coincides with the maximal dimension of an abelian *ideal* for nilpotent Lie algebras.

Comment: That there is no abelian subalgebra of dimension $\ge n+2$ is trivial: it would project to an isotropic subspace of dimension $\ge n+1$ in a $2n$-dimensional symplectic vector space and it's clear that this does not exist.